# Linux: Is it possible to know if my kernel has support for "policy routing" enabled?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-kernel

I am following [these instructions](http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/) in order to configure multiple default routes for Linux (I am testing it on Ubuntu v12.04 and Kali v1.0.6), and the feature "policy routing" is requested enabled in the kernel.
How could I know if it is enabled or disabled?
Maybe Linux command-line has some generic command tool that reports about a requested feature in Kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in:

```
/proc/config.gz
/boot/config
/boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

and search for appropriate option
If it will be enabled there should be:

```
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES="Y"
```

or similar.
You can use grep for that. 
In case you would have /proc/config.gz. You need unpack it first.

Comment: I only have one of these files (/boot/config-3.12-kali1-686-pae). But there inside is the info requested, so the response is correct. And the method seems that will work for any other kind of research of feature enabled inside the kernel. Thanks you, @ahaw.

Comment: Method not working for RaspBerry, it seems, as none of these files do exist.